# Nav menu won't show

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, nav

I can't get my nav menu to show anything but the gray header (no 3 lines for the menu)... I know it's obvious but I don't see my mistake.

```
  <header>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
      </nav>
  </header>

<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You're loading bootstraps css right because you have all the JS in your question but no CSS reference.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't referenced the boostrap.css file. Here's a working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bp9h3nyf/). 
Just add this line to your `<head>` html.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
```

This will show the three lines you needed.